# Using dbms_scheduler to run a program

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

I am trying to run a program using scheduler job.My code goes as follows:

```
--Program
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_program (
    program_name    =>  'firstprogram',
    program_type    =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    program_action  =>  'BEGIN Execute immediate ''Create table xyz(id int, name varchar2(10))''; end;',
    enabled         =>  TRUE,
    comments        =>  'First program');

END;
/
--Schedule
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_schedule (
    schedule_name   => 'firstschedule',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byhour=14; byminute=25',
    end_date        => NULL,
    comments        => 'Repeats daily');
END;
/
--Job
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_job (
    job_name      =>  'firstjob',
    program_name  =>  'firstprogram',
    schedule_name =>  'firstschedule',
    enabled       =>  TRUE,
    comments      =>  'Use firstprogram and FirstSchedule');
END;
/
```

All these code blocks compile without showing any errors. But the table `xyz` is not created in the specified time. Can anyone explain me why? I am using Oracle.

Comment: You have scheduled it to run daily at `14:25`, did it run at least once?

Comment: It was 14:23 when I compiled the program. The table xyz should be created at 14:25, but it didn't happen.

Comment: Check the view `dba_scheduler_jobs`.

Comment: It exists there with the enabled set to TRUE.

Comment: There are other columns `RUN_COUNT`, `FAILURE_COUNT` etc.

Comment: select * from user_scheduler_job_log;
select * from user_scheduler_job_run_details;

Comment: I don't understand what you guys are suggesting.

Comment: Run the query select * from user_scheduler_job_run_details;
and check if there are details regarding your scheduled job.

or
if you use sql developer check in the scheduler for your scheduled job. If it is not found then it does not created.

Comment: The system time varies with the database server time. Maybe this was the problem? And which time should I use to create the schedule?